# Apache POI falls with exception when creates sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

While creating a new sheet in my xml, POI falls with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find 'internal references' EXTERNALBOOK
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.LinkTable.checkExternSheet(LinkTable.java:436) ~[system-monitor-server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.checkSheets(InternalWorkbook.java:741) ~[system-monitor-server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.setSheetName(InternalWorkbook.java:585) ~[system-monitor-server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:789) ~[system-monitor-server.jar:?]
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:73) ~[system-monitor-server.jar:?]
```

The code:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(RAW_REPORT_XLS));
Sheet myNewSheet = workbook.createSheet(WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName("TestSheet"));
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Can you try with POI 3.11-beta1? There have been quite a [few fixes recently](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.11-beta1) around external formulas and external names

Answer (score 0):

I got this error msg using HSSF clonesheet (poi version 3.14)
The template was an xls file saved using LibreOffice.
When i opened the template and saved it in excel 2010 I got a larger file and this solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your template has some mistakes. It could be some external references, such as cells in another workbook.